# Sum of angles $m\angle (x, y)(0, 0)(0, 1)$ for $0 \le x, y \le 5$

Tags: trigonometry, analytic-geometry, angle

The Problem:

Denote by $V_{(x, y)}$ the vertex at ordered pair $(x, y)$ in the Cartesian coordinate system. Denote by $A_{(x, y)}$ the measure of angle $\angle V_{(x, y)}V_{(0, 0)}V_{(1, 0)}$. Let
$$\theta = \sum_{0 \le i, j \le 5 \ \ (i, j) \neq (0, 0)}{A_{(i, j)}}$$
Find $\theta \pmod{2\pi}$.

I understand the question and everything, but I am slightly overwhelmed about how to find an organized approach to computing the sum of angles. I got the value down to the sum
$$\sum_{0 \le i, j \le 5 \ \ (i, j) \neq (0, 0)}{\arctan{\frac ij}}$$
But I don't know how to evaluate this. $\arctan(x+y)$ formula fails. I think there is a different approach I am not aware of.

Is there a nice way to generalize to
$$\sum_{0 \le i, j \le k \ \ (i, j) \neq (0, 0)}{A_{(i, j)}}$$

Comment: Hint: find a relation between $A_{(i,j)}$  and $A_{(j,i)}$

Comment: $A(0,0)$ doesn't seem to be well defined but appears to be part of the sum

Comment: @above, fixed. $A_{(0, 0)}$ is not part of the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now, Note that if we represent $A_{m, n}+A_{n, m}$ in terms of complex numbers we get $\arg{(m+ni)(n+mi)}=\pi/2$. There are $k(k+1)$ of these numbers (ignnoring diagonals so we get $(k(k+1)/2)(\pi/2)$. Adding back the diagonal (ignoring $(0, 0)$) we get $k\pi/4$. $$(k(k+1)/2)(\pi/2)+k\pi/4=\frac{k(k+2)\pi}{4}$$ Which is the general solution. Substituting $k=5$ gives $35\pi/4 \equiv 3\pi/4 \pmod{2\pi}$